# Chaining vimgrep and copen with Vim

Tags: vim

This is what I do when I have to recursively search for a pattern in some directories:

```
:vimgrep 'some-pattern' app/views/**
```

and then, I have to type:

```
:copen 20
```

So I can finally see the list of files containing "some-pattern" in the quikfix window with 20 lines.

It perfectly fit my needs, but is there any way to chain those 2 commands, so every time I'm asking for a vimgrep, it "pipes" the results to the quickfix window has if I typed ":copen 20"?

As much as possible, I'd prefer to stick to standard stuff (any .vimrc based method?), and avoid using a plugin for finding in files.

I switched to Vim just a week ago, thank you for your help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could add this snippet to your `vimrc`:

```
" create a self-clearing autocommand group called 'qf'
augroup qf
    " clear all autocommands in this group
    autocmd!

    " do :cwindow if the quickfix command doesn't start
    " with a 'l' (:grep, :make, etc.)
    autocmd QuickFixCmdPost [^l]* cwindow

    " do :lwindow if the quickfix command starts with
    " a 'l' (:lgrep, :lmake, etc.)
    autocmd QuickFixCmdPost l*    lwindow

    " do :cwindow when Vim was started with the '-q' flag
    autocmd VimEnter        *     cwindow
augroup END
```

This will automatically open the quickfix/location window whenever you do `:vimgrep` or other commands that populate the quickfix/location list *and* there are qualified matches.

Examples:

```
:vim foo **/*.js
:lgrep bar *.rb
$ vim -q <(grep baz test.txt)
```

See `:help autocmd` and `:help :cwindow`.

Comment: This looks like exactly what I need, but I'm struggling a bit to understand how it works. From what I gather, the "only if there are qualified matches" is handled by the `:cwindow` command entirely. Also, I assume that the `VimEnter` hook is used to support the `-q` command. But why these `[^l]*` and `l*` patterns? AFAIU these are matched against the current filename, but won't *any* non-empty string necessarily match either of these patterns?

Comment: `[^l]*` and `l*` are matched against the quickfix command that triggered the event. `l*` will match all quickfix commands that start with a `l` like `:lmake`, `:lgrep`, etc. and `[^l]*` will match the rest. The former is used to identify commands that populate the location list and thus do `:lwindow`. The latter is used to identify commands that populate the quickfix list and thus do `:cwindow`.

Comment: @MatthijsKooijman I've added comments to the snippet (and fixed a typo).

Comment: Ah, that typo fix explains a lot, before both lines would execute `cwindow`, now one does `lwindow`. Thanks for the clarifications and added comments!

Answer (score 0):

Haha! Pipes, yeah... I just tried randomly:

```
:vimgrep 'some-pattern' app/views/** | copen 20
```

And it worked! Anyway, if anyone has a tip to append it automatically after each vimgrep, my question is still open... (you may also justify if it's a bad idea, which would be possible).

Comment: This is not pipe. In vim this is called `bar`. Try `:help :bar`